# How can I prevent Text suggestions in an Entry in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to disable text suggestions for a Xamarin.Forms entry? I expected that this is done by `IsTextPredictionEnabled = false`, but this value seems to have no affect on the Entry, at least as of Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2291.

I have created a test screen with the following code:

```
var entry1 = new Entry();
entry1.Text = "Default";
entry1.WidthRequest = 300;
entry1.IsSpellCheckEnabled = true;
entry1.IsTextPredictionEnabled = true;
absoluteLayout.Children.Add(entry1);

var entry2 = new Entry();
entry2.IsSpellCheckEnabled = false;
entry2.IsTextPredictionEnabled = false;
entry2.Text = "No SpellCheck/Prediction";
entry2.WidthRequest = 300;
entry2.Margin = new Thickness (0, 60, 0, 0);
absoluteLayout.Children.Add(entry2);
```

This produces the following behavior. Notice that both entries behave the same regardless of the `IsSpellCheckEnabled` or `IsTextPredictionEnabled` values.

[image]

According to the documentation here, this should work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.entry.istextpredictionenabled?view=xamarin-forms

Also here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry

Nothing came up in my searches to indicate that this is broken, so maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use custom renderer and try to set InputTypes as TextVariationVisiblePassword,this works well on my side.Below is the code snippets for your reference.

```
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {

            new MyEntry {
                Text = "No SpellCheck/Prediction",
                IsSpellCheckEnabled= false,
                IsTextPredictionEnabled = false,
                WidthRequest=300
                }
        },
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        };
```

MyRenderer class:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace AppTestEntry.Droid
{
class MyRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    public MyRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationVisiblePassword;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Document for custom renderer for your reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry

[image]